# android ftp upload has stopped error

Tags: android, networking, upload, background, ftp

```
 class Asenkron extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Long> 
    { 

        @Override
         protected Long doInBackground(String... aurl) 
        {
         FTPClient con=null; 
        try 
        { 
            con = new FTPClient(); 
            con.connect(aurl[0]); 

            if (con.login(aurl[1], aurl[2])) 
            { 
                con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
                 con.setFileType(http://FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE); 
                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(aurl[3])); 
                boolean result = con.storeFile(aurl[3], in); 
                in.close(); 
                con.logout(); 
                con.disconnect();
             } 
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return null;
    }



    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {}
}
```

**I AM USING THIS CLASS LIKE BELOW.THERE IS BUTTON AND WHENEVER I CLICK THE BUTTON IT SHOULD START FTP UPLOAD PROCESS IN BACKGROUND BUT I GET "PROGRAM HAS STOPPED UNFORTUNATELY" ERROR.**
        Assume that The ftp address and username password pathfile sections are true and I get the internet and network permissions already by the way ...

```
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            new Asenkron().execute("ftpaddress","username","pass","pathfileon telephone"); 
        }
   });
```

And here is the logcat for you to analyse the potential error and help me ...

```
10-13 13:01:25.591: I/dalvikvm(633): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-13 13:01:25.711: I/dalvikvm(633): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-13 13:01:25.921: D/gralloc_goldfish(633): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-13 13:01:31.441: W/dalvikvm(633): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
10-13 13:01:31.461: E/AndroidRuntime(633): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
10-13 13:01:31.461: E/AndroidRuntime(633): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-13 13:01:31.461: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
10-13 13:01:31.461: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
10-13 13:01:31.461: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
10-13 13:01:31.461: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
10-13 13:01:31.461: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-13 13:01:31.461: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
10-13 13:01:31.461: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-13 13:01:31.461: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-13 13:01:31.461: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-13 13:01:31.461: E/AndroidRuntime(633): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
10-13 13:01:31.461: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
10-13 13:01:31.461: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:317)
10-13 13:01:31.461: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:91)
10-13 13:01:31.461: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:233)
10-13 13:01:31.461: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at com.example.ftpodak.ODAK$Asenkron.doInBackground(ODAK.java:74)
10-13 13:01:31.461: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at com.example.ftpodak.ODAK$Asenkron.doInBackground(ODAK.java:1)
10-13 13:01:31.461: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
10-13 13:01:31.461: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-13 13:01:31.461: E/AndroidRuntime(633):  ... 5 more
```

---

By the way I changed the relevant code like that ;

instead of

```
catch (Exception e) 
  {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
```

I replaced with this code

```
catch (Exception e) 
  {
     HATA=e.toString();
  }
```

And I added the code to button

```
textview1.setText(HATA);
```

So I can see the error on the textview and it is writing that 
"Android java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved"

But i know that the ftp server is correct and I check the ftp server from the AndFTP application.
With the same address login and pass information ftp server is working.So the problem is in my code I think.Any help will be too much appreciated.Anyone who can help me I can give teamviewer to analyse what is the problem ...

Comment: sorry but where is the error log ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a hint of the problem from this line: `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`. You're trying to execute a UI operation from a thread that is not the main thread. All UI changes should be executed from the main thread.

Comment out this line and it'll work:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Instead of showing the toast to notify the user of the exception, use a `boolean` to tell the `Activity` subclass(that calls the `async` task) that there had been an exception and show a toast accordingly.

**EDIT-** The Library you're using might not be able to do the job, so you can just shift to a new library, like the [apache commons ftp](http://commons.apache.org/net/download_net.cgi). Refer [this blog](http://lavalatwork.blogspot.in/2010/09/using-apache-commons-ftp-library-in.html) to see how to use it.

**EDIT2-** If in `con.connect(aurl[0]);`, `aurl[0]` already contains `http://***`, you'll have to remove `http://` because the ftp client appends it later (causing the unknown host). Also change this line `con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);`(remove the `http://` part)

Comment: Yes removing the Toast command line helps me about not getting program has stopped error.But still it cannot upload the file to my ftpserver.

Comment: I use already apache commons-net-ftp-2.0 library on my project.

Comment: Can you just tell me with the same codes and your ftp address information the program is working or not ? Have you tried it with your ftp address ?

Comment: Edited answer. See `con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);`. remove http:// in that line

Comment: I removed it but it is same by the way is it possible for you to help me with teamviewer I will really appreciate that.After we find the real problem we will publish it from here again

Answer (score 0):

I cannot figure out but let's see my real code and evaluate ;
My real code is like that

new Asenkron().execute("ftp://liseacy:gokgok81@ftp.drivehq.com/","liseacy","gokgok81","/mnt/extSdCard/MUZIK/VERIBAK.TXT");

and that ftp information correct because I can upload file with ANDftp application without any problem...

I also tried below code and it has not worked too

new Asenkron().execute("liseacy:gokgok81@ftp.drivehq.com/","liseacy","gokgok81","/mnt/extSdCard/MUZIK/VERIBAK.TXT");

and I tried this also not worked ;

new Asenkron().execute("ftp.drivehq.com/","liseacy","gokgok81","/mnt/extSdCard/MUZIK/VERIBAK.TXT");